# How to bind Observablecollection<T> with combobox in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate, observablecollection

I am trying to bind `Observablecollection<T>` with `ComboBox`. `ComboBox` having `Datatemplete`

```
<ComboBox Width="150" Margin="20,0,0,5" Name="cbSelection" Height="20" 
              BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" 
              SelectedIndex="0" DataContext="{Binding AdComboBox}">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding XPath=LOC, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding XPath=PUB, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding XPath=EDI, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
```

but not get the data in `ComboBox`
what going wrong
thanks in advance

Comment: Bind Combobox.ItemsSource property

Comment: you should bind to Path and not to XPath

Answer (score 2):

Use the ItemsSource of the ComboBox to point to the `ObservableCollection<T>`. Also: Use Path, not XPath which is used for binding to XML documents.

```
<ComboBox Width="150" Margin="20,0,0,5" Name="cbSelection" Height="20" 
          BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding AdComboBox}"
          SelectedIndex="0">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" 
                           Text="{Binding Path=LOC, Mode=OneWay}"
                           Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" 
                           Text="{Binding Path=PUB, Mode=OneWay}"
                           Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" 
                           Text="{Binding Path=EDI, Mode=OneWay}"
                           Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Side note: you might want to rename the collection to something more functional instead of *AdComboBox*. E.g., *Ads* Because it is not a ComboBox but it is a collection of Ads(?)